# AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: bot

Tags: python, flask

Does anyone know why I'm getting this overwrite error? I only have two functions and have a single route that can't overwrite an existing endpoint function. I'm running python3 routes.py, thanks!

routes.py

```
from flask import request
from __init__ import app, _update_db
from models import User
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

def _send_message(output_lines):
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg = resp.message()
    msg.body("\n".join(output_lines))
    return str(resp)



@app.route("/bot", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def bot():
    output_lines = []
    incoming_msg = request.values.get('Body', '').lower()
    remote_number = request.values.get('From')
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg = resp.message()
    responded = False
    user = User.query.get(remote_number)
```

Traceback

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "routes.py", line 14, in <module>
    @app.route("/bot", methods=["POST", "GET"])
  File ".../Projects/wisdom/wisdom-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1315, in decorator
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File ".../Projects/wisdom/wisdom-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 98, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../Projects/wisdom/wisdom-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1284, in add_url_rule
    "existing endpoint function: %s" % endpoint
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: bot
```